# Radio button into images created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I want to change the checked radio btn by clicking on an image who is created dynamically. This is the PHP generating my image:

```
<?php if($subject_list){
      foreach ($subject_list as $item):?>
            <input type="radio" name="subjectagendaactivity" value="male" />
            <img src="/static/images/school/students/subjects/island/island_<?php echo $item['id'];?>_agenda.png"/>
      <?php endforeach;}?>
```

So my images are generated like this and this is the code i made in JQuery to be able to change the .cheked:

```
$(this).click(function () {
                $('input:radio[name=subjectagendaactivity]')[0].checked = true;
            });
```

I need to change the [0] into a $(this) or something like this so my radio btn is checked when i click on the right image.

Comment: Do the `img` tags come out with IDs or classes?

Comment: i can add an ID if i need one, no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?: http://jsfiddle.net/FsshJ/ The only downside is that it requires both the `img` and the `input` to have IDs. However, you could change it to something else if you wanted/needed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).click(function () {
                $('input:radio[name=subjectagendaactivity]').attr("checked", true);
            });
```

Comment: When i do so, it always check the last box

Comment: Thank you for your help, i appreciate it. Problem is solve by Andrew peacock if you want to see how i did, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).click(checkIt($(this)));



// Elsewhere
function checkIt(rBtn) {
    rBtn.checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input:radio[name=subjectagendaactivity]').each(function(index) {
if(index == 0)
{
     $(this).attr("checked","checked");
     return;
}
});
```

Comment: Not working, telling me $("input:radio[name=subjectagendaactivity]")[0].attr is not a function

Comment: Still was not working, maybe i was doing something wrong. Thank you anyway problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the checkbox you want to check is always the element *before* the image you're clicking on:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    var $check = $(this).prev(':checkbox');

    if($check.is(':checked'){  // Already checked? Uncheck it!
        $check.removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else{
        $check.attr('checked','checked');
    }
});
```

Take a look at [jQuery's traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/); you should be able to find one that will allow you to grab your checkboxes by convention.